# error with "package main" flagging red in the main.go folder

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, microservices

I have written a `main.go` program and declared the package at the beginning of the code but it flagging red as shown below:
[image: see the flag on the package main]

When I hover on the package, it displays the following:

```
gopls requires a module at the root of your workspace.
You can work with multiple modules by opening each one as a workspace folder.
Improvements to this workflow will be coming soon, and you can learn more here:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md.
```

I'd require help on how I can pass this error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting started with golang, so I'm not sure if this would help you.

This error was showing up here in VS Code, and to solve it I needed to clone an empty github repo into a new folder, to add the main.go file later.

I was able to add, commit and push changes. The lint error is now gone.

In my case, .git folder is located upwards, and not alongside main.go:

```
\my-app
  |
  |__ \backend
      |__ go.mod
      |__ main.go
  |__ \frontend
  |__ \.git
```

Within the backend folder the go.mod was generated with

```
go mod init github.com/<your-username>/my-app
```

It seems GitHub changed the default branch from master to main. If you use github, check if your in the correct branch, which may be `main` by default.

Comment: Is using a github the only way to do this? I dont have a git repository and dont want one for what im doing.i have go.mod but im still seeing the error

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the command `go mod init` from your command line at the root of the project.  It looks like you ran it from `go-microservice/prod-api`, but it should be run at the same place where your `.git` lives.  If `prod-api` is in fact the root of the git project, then you need to open that folder in VSCode instead of `go-microservice`.

Answer (score 0):

If you move hello.go to the root folder of GO-MICROSERVICE from prod-api, then you will not have an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this issue by adding `"build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true` in gopls settings
[This mentioned in the link appear in the error](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the solution is very simple, like it was in my case. In my case it was as simple as the hierarchy of the folder i opened in VSCode.

[image]

If you look at my project hierarchy, I was getting the error when in VSCode I opened the folder called "start", which is the immediate folder where main.go was is. I was getting the highlighted red package error like you.

Then in VSCode, I selected "open folder", and opened the project one level above, folder "go_start_code". The error went away.